# Find full paths to all leaf nodes?

Tags: json, graph, quickgraph

I'm using QuickGraph to create a graph of (P)roducts and the properties associated in them, (T)ype, (S)ubtype and (F)requency.

So in this example, I have 2 products P1 & P2:

- P1 is assigned properties T1, S1 & S2, F1
- P2 is assigned properties T1, S1, F1 & F2

The directed, unweighted graph looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to use this generate a JSON object to hold the full paths to all products? Something like:

```
{T1: [
    {S1: [
        {F1: [
            P1,P2
        ]},
        {F2: [
            P2
        ]}
    ]},
    {S2: [
        {F1: [
            P1
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

I initially looked at DepthFirstSearchAlgorithm and its DiscoverVertex event, which will walk the graph by depth but the this event is only triggered when a **new** vertex is discovered so I get T1,S1,F1,P1,P2,F2,S2.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This actually proved at lot easier than I thought. I simply walked the graph using OutEdges in a recursive function, creating a hierarchical Xml document as I went. This final Xml was then serialized into JSON using Json.Net!

Comment: Hi Neil it would be awesome to see your approach. You could mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: This seems like mainly a question about graph traversal; writing to JSON is a secondary aspect.